# Check Git Status in PowerShell with condition

Tags: git, powershell

I need to check the git status and find all files which is not ".txt" format.

I know how to find all files which is in this format:

```
$TextFiles = $(git status --short *.txt --porcelain | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand Count)
```

How can I do the same but to retrieve all other files with NO text format??

I've tried this way but it didn't work...

```
$NoTextFiles = $(git status --short -ne *.txt --porcelain | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:!` for your git pathspec ([see gitglossary for more info](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec))

```
git status --short ':!*.txt'
```

But when you have staged entire directories this command will only list the directory name not its content.
If you want to list every file that is not *.txt you should do this with powershell:

```
git status --short '*.*' | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch ".*\.txt"}
```